# Prisma postgresql many-to-many multiple fields

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, prisma, ambiguous

I'm trying to define the relationships in Prisma where:

- There's a Post model
- There's a Tag model
- Each Post can have multiple primaryTags: Tag[], and multiple secondaryTags: Tag[]

So, seems like both primary and secondary tags relations would reference the same PostTag table.
In one to many we'd use a named relation. Not sure how to deal with that in many to many.

```
model Post {
   id @id @default(cuid())
   primaryTags Tag[]
   secondaryTags Tag[]
}

model Tag {
   id @id @default(cuid())
   name String
}

model PostTag {
   postId String
   post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
   tagId String
   tag @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id])
   @@id([postId, tagId])
}
```

I guess, if I was doing it without Prisma, I'd set an additional property `isPrimary` on the PostTag table. But not sure if it's the right way to go here. Also, that's probably not doable if defining implicit many-to-many Prisma-recommended way.

One other way I could think of is to define 2 separate relationship tables - one for primary tags, one for secondary. Not sure if that's too much though.